# subclipse Issue after switching to using SVNParentPath

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

I've had Subclipse set up and working correctly.  Recently I needed to create a 2nd repository in SVN for another project in a separate Eclipse workspace.  Up to this point my `dav_svn.conf` file was setup to only provide access to the first repository. So I created the new repository. Then I enabled the `SVNParentPath` and `SVNListParentPath` directives, did *not* change the `<Location URL>`, and verified that it was working ok by just using my web browser on the client PC and everything was great.

But when I tested it in Eclipse, if I use the SVN Repository Exploring view,  Subclipse insists that the repository can't be found - none of the Team functions work. Nor will it list the other repository that should be available at that URL if I just try to create a new repository.

Do I need to relocate the repository via SVN Repository Exploring View? (despite the dire warnings)  Or is there actually something wrong with Subclipse?

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.04, along with:

- org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature (1.8.6) "Subversion Client Adapter"
- org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.feature (1.7.10) "Subversion JavaHL"
- org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature (1.7.9.2) "SVNKit Client Adapter"
- org.tigris.subversion.subclipse (1.8.22) "SVN Team Provider Core"
- org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.graph.feature (1.1.1) "Subversion Revision Graph"

the subversion repository is hosted on a Ubuntu server (10.04 LTS) and being served via Apache using the `dav_svn` 'plugin'.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the URL for the repository has changed, so yes you would need to take the Relocate option so that you can update the URL.  Note that you have to give Subclipse the URL to one of your repositories, not to the parent path.  No SVN client will accept the URL to the parent.  So, for example, the URL needs to be:

http://server.com/svn/repos

- not -

http://server.com/svn

I do not believe the message when you do Relocate is "dire" it is just letting you know what it is going to do.

Comment: Thanks you So much.  Especially for clarifying the fact that the path needs to still be specific to the actual repository.  Sorry about the "dire", I just get frustrated and sometimes feel like working with the tools needed to manage writing the code is harder than the actual writing of the code.  :-)